# Show progress in dynamically generated progress bar in Windows application

Tags: c#

I have a few progress bars which are created in run time on a button click.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int count=0; 
    for(var item in items)
    {
        count++;
        ProgressBar pBar = new ProgressBar();
        pBar.Name = "progressBar1_"+count;
        pBar.Width = 200;
        pBar.Height = 15;
        pBar.Minimum = 1;
        pBar.Maximum = 100;
        pBar.Value = 1;
        Panel1.Controls.Add(pBar);
```

How do I access the dynamically created progress bar to show progress?

```
"progressBar1_"+count.PerformStep();// This doesnt work
```

Comment: You need to be a little more specific...how should we know which progress bar you want to show your progress on?

Comment: how you gonna update the progress?

Comment: I have edited the question.. Hope my question is clear now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your for loop every time you call

```
ProgressBar pBar = new ProgressBar();
```

you create an new instance of an progress bar.

One option is to remember this instance in an list or dictionary.

Something like that:

```
List<string> items = new List<string>() { "item" };

Dictionary<string, ProgressBar> progressBars = new Dictionary<string, ProgressBar>();

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int count=0; 
    foreach(var item in items)
    {
        count++;
        ProgressBar pBar = new ProgressBar();
        pBar.Name = "progressBar_" + count;
        pBar.Width = 200;
        pBar.Height = 15;
        pBar.Minimum = 1;
        pBar.Maximum = 100;
        pBar.Value = 1;
        panel1.Controls.Add(pBar);

        progressBars.Add(pBar.Name, pBar);
    }
}

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    progressBars["progressBar_1"].PerformStep();
}
```

The second option is to search for this instance in the controls of your panel.

```
List<string> items = new List<string>() { "item" };

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int count=0; 
    foreach(var item in items)
    {
        count++;
        ProgressBar pBar = new ProgressBar();
        pBar.Name = "progressBar_" + count;
        pBar.Width = 200;
        pBar.Height = 15;
        pBar.Minimum = 1;
        pBar.Maximum = 100;
        pBar.Value = 1;
        panel1.Controls.Add(pBar);

        progressBars.Add(pBar.Name, pBar);
    }
}

private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    (panel1.Controls.Find("progressBar_1", false).Single() as ProgressBar).PerformStep();
}
```